# Maven compiler, only compile annotated classes

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, annotations, maven-compiler-plugin

I've created a custom Java annotation (code below) in a Maven 2 project I'm working on:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MYANNOTATION{}
```

At one part of the Maven build, I only want to compile classes annotated with this annotation, e.g:

```
@MYANNOTATION
public class MyClass {
    // Code here
}
```

I'm currently using the [Maven Compiler Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) to restrict complication based on package structure. My pom.xml contains resembles the one below, restricting compilation to classes in **com.foo.bar.stuff** and **com.baz.foo.more**. This is unsatisfactory, because when I add annotated classes to com.xyz.bar.foo, I must remember to define it in the pom.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>default-compile</id>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <includes>
                <include>**/com/foo/bar/stuff/**</include>
                <include>**/com/baz/foo/more/**</include>
              </includes>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Is there any way to define Maven to compile only classes that have been annotated with this annotation, not depending on where they are located in the package hierarchy?

(I'm trying to generate a metamodel from domain model classes so I can point to fields & methods without defining the names as String constants - and changing them manually when I refactor)

**Edit:** I am already doing annotation processing in another part of the build phase. The system works like this:

1. Compile classes in the specified packages
2. Using [JAnnocessor](http://www.jannocessor.org/), build metamodels from classes with @MYANNOTATION
3. Compile the rest of the classes

Dependencies from other classes to the metamodel classes prevent compiling everything in one go, unless we move the annotated classes to a different project and add a dependency to it. That's one possibility but can add complexity, because the current project structure appears to form a logical whole.

Comment: An annotation processor will perform processing on classes that have the requested annotation, but the source code would need to be  parsed first by the compiler so that the annotations can be found. The only way I can see to restrict the input set of java files to the compiler to just those files with a set of annotations is via something like a grep over the entire set of source files (maybe the ant plugin can be used here). But even then the compiler will also load referenced classes and you may end up parsing the whole source tree anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something similar to what you want with annotation processing. I don't think there's any maven-specific thing you need to do, but you need to write an annotation processor that has to either be part of a separate library or compiled separately.

The concept of annotation processing is explained pretty well in this blog entry:

> [Code Generation using Annotation Processors in the Java language –
>   part 2: Annotation Processors](http://deors.wordpress.com/2011/10/08/annotation-processors/)